# The parameter vbNormalNoFocus of the shell command does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I write a script in Excel to call VC program. I want to keep the focus in Excel after running.

```
...
strPath = "xxx.exe"
X = Shell(strPath, vbNormalNoFocus)
...
```

But the focus is still on VC program after running. The parameter vbNormalNoFocus of the shell command does not work. How can I do to keep the focus on EXECL?

I don't want to use `application.Wait(now + TimeValue ("0:00:05") VBA.AppActivate "11.xlsx"`.

Here is a [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) of shell function.

Comment: If I run `shell "cmd /k dir c:\", vbNormalNoFocus` it pops up on top of the screen, but it doesn't have focus. Test this. • If it is differently whith your `xxx.exe` that means it steals focus and you probably cannot prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [AppActivate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/appactivate-statement) statement

```
...
strPath = "xxx.exe"
X = Shell(strPath, vbNormalFocus)
AppActivate X ' Will set the focus on xxx.exe
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel" ' Will set the focus on  Excel
...
```

Comment: Thank you.I don't want to use `appactivate`. 
 `vbnormalnofocus` is effective for other windows programs such as Notepad.
It seems that my exe program actively gets the focus. How can I modify my program?

Comment: @lin we cannot tell your how to change your program.exe because we don't know what it does and how. Obviously it steals the focus when starting. You probably need to ask a new question for that and you need to tell much more about your program and in which language it is coded. This cannot be solved in a comment. • Finally I see no issue using `AppActivate` in this case if it works. Looks like a solid solution to me to make it work easily.